# How to get the base url of a specific store view in a static block?

Tags: magento, static-block

I know that in a .phtml file you do it like this for example:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('derco_core')->getStoreUrl('dcmotosesp')?>
```

I want to do the same thing inside a static block. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `derco_core` is not a standard helper alias. Do you have an extension installed? Also there is no `getStoreUrl` in any core helpers.

Comment: This already works in a phtml file. Its just a example of what i need to do in the static block. What i need is a command like the {{store url=""}} but that gets the base url of a specific store view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no 'clean' way of getting an url for a specific store using shortcodes (`{{store url}}`).
...because the `store` shortcode handler end like this (see `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::storeDirective()`):

```
return Mage::app()->getStore(Mage::getDesign()->getStore())->getUrl($path, $params);
```

This means that the store cannot be passed as a parameter.

The following might work but it's a bit ugly. The idea is to send the parameter `___store` through `$_GET` telling Magento to switch to a specific store.

```
<a href="{{store url="some/url/here" _query="___store=store_code_here"}}">TEST LINK</a>
```

(replace 'store_code_here' with your specific store code).

An other option would be to extend the method mentioned above and allow it to receive a `store_code` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for explaining where in the code this *bug* stems from.  (a bug in my mind as it seems `{{store url=""}}` which comes from the core template doesn't work as expected when using more than one store...  poor design.  I was linking the logo in the email to the homepage and thus `{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}` worked for my purposes.